# MySQL COUNT Giving DIfferent Results

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli

If I use this in PHP to count records, it gives a count of 1 when there are, in fact, no records. However, when I run the same query in HeidiSQL, phpmyadmin or any other, it gives the proper 0. Why the discrepancy?

```
if ($result = $mysqli->query($Query)) :
    return $result->num_rows;
    $MySQLError = ($mysqli->connect_errno) ? mysqli_error($mysqli) : "";
    $result->close();
    $mysqli->close();
    if ($MySQLError) return $MySQLError;
endif;
```

$Query, in this case, contains:

```
SELECT COUNT(ID) AS UpdateCount 
FROM tablename 
WHERE ShowPage = 1 AND 
DateUpdated BETWEEN 1554345942 AND 1554950742
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While working on something else, the answer to this problem suddenly hit me and it's obvious now that I see it. I was using ***COUNT(ID)*** in the query but also using ***$result->num_rows*** in the programming. Simply removing the COUNT(ID) did the trick.

```
SELECT ID 
FROM tablename 
WHERE ShowPage = 1 AND 
DateUpdated BETWEEN 1554345942 AND 1554950742
```

Comment: Well done for finding it.  Accept and upvote your answer so future visitors with the same or similar problems can benefit!

Comment: @Don't Panic Thank you and I'm feeling a bit foolish about it but I was sure it was something obvious that I had missed. I'm surprised that the sharp eyes here didn't spot it instantly! Anyway, I can't up-vote my own answer and I see that someone down-voted it for some unknown reason but I can mark it as accepted if I wait nine more hours.

Answer (score -1):

This issue  might occur if another database session has not yet been committed. Making sure that there are no other database sessions which have not been committed solves this problem.

Comment: Possibly but it seems consistently incorrect even when no other queries have been run. Always correct in HeidiSQL and phpmyadmin but never in PHP so I suspect it's something more basic than that which I have missed. Odd, I've been using this same code for a long time and only just noticed the problem.